# "Android resource linking failed" al hacer downgrade de version de SDK 28 a SDK 27

Tags: android, gradle, sdk

Tengo una aplicación que se termino actualizando para usar el SDK 28, todo bien, hasta que después se tuvo que integrar una librería que estrictamente funciona hasta SDK 27, al hacer los cambios en el gradle y darle a sync, no me tira ningun error en código, pero al lanzar la aplicación me tira lo siguiente:

```
Android resource linking failed
/Users/arthur/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7226867a41f5d4ccc72cc826a012cabd/support-compat-28.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

/Users/arthur/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/7226867a41f5d4ccc72cc826a012cabd/support-compat-28.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

/Users/arthur/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/c7a75a33222743f92f572d548018913e/video-android-5.1.0/res/values/values.xml:13:5-17:25: AAPT: error: resource attr/overlaySurface (aka com.parallax.android:attr/overlaySurface) not found.
```

Dejo una muestra de mi gradle app.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

//Crashlytics
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    signingConfigs {
        staging {
            //Cosas
        }
        release {
            //Cosas
        }
        debug{
            //Cosas
        }
    }

    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mi.nombre"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 28
        versionName "1.3.19"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            //Cosas
        }
        staging {
            //cosas
        }

        // TODO Agregar llaves de produccion
        release {
            //cosas
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(":MoverioSDK_1.0.1")

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.8'

    //HTTP API
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    //implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1'

    // Including webrtc
//    implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.30039'
    // socket.io
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:1.7.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg-aar:1.3'
    // Zoom at imageview
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

    // Firebase Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'

    // Google Sign In SDK (only required for Google Sign In)
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    // Firebase UI
    // Used in FirebaseUIActivity.
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'

    // Facebook Android SDK (only required for Facebook Login)
    // Used in FacebookLoginActivity.
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'

    // Twitter Android SDK (only required for Twitter Login)
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.3.0'

    //push notification
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'

    //Twilio
    //implementation "com.twilio:video-android:${versions.videoAndroid}"
    implementation 'com.twilio:video-android:5.1.0'

    // (Recommended) Add Analytics -- Si se agrega esta depencia, es necesario migrar a AndroidX
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'

    // Add dependency
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```

***He buscado y encuentro que lo solucionan usando en la version 28, pero estrictamente tengo que usar la 27.***

Gracias de antemano.

***** UPDATE : *****

Entiendo que esos componentes son de la version de SDK 28(Que no existen en la 27), pero necesito encontrar la manera de bajarlos de version.

Agregue esto en la configuración de mi gradle. En build.gradle, en la sección allprojects. Aun no funciona.

```
allprojects {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.Android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste que las demás librerías funcionen con la versión 27?

Comment: Las que son externas a android, osea, todas las que se agregaron abajo en dependencies, si.